# Bash: getopts passes a flag as wrong argument

Tags: bash, getopts

I am trying to run a command that has multiple arguments.  The command syntax is like so:

```
./foo -d directory -f file -v version app1 app2 app3 (this situation works)
```

However if I put the `-v version` after `app1,2,3` it is passed as an argument and not the `-v` flag.  How do I get the `-v` flag to work in either position with multiple arguments?

```
while getopts ":d:f:v:" OPTION

do
    case $OPTION in


            d ) IFS=","; directory=$OPTARG;;
            f ) file=$OPTARG;;
            v ) version=$OPTARG;;
            * ) echo && usage;;
            /? ) echo && usage;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

for dir in ${dirList} do
 for f in ${file} ; do
  echo $dir/$file
done
 done

applications=$@
```

Comment: `getopts` stops parsing on the first non-option argument (skipping option args).

Answer (score 2):

The standard option processing in Unix stops at the first non-option (excluding arguments for options marked with `:`). This is somewhat important, because otherwise you could not handle any files or directories starting with `-`.

If you really must break these rules, you can try the external program `getopt(1)`, which uses a library function `getopt(3)`. Reading the manual page for that function there are some remarks regarding argument shuffling. These may help you.

Comment: Thanks will give the other getopt(1,3) a try

Answer (score 0):

You could define it using getopt so that you do something like:

```
./foo -d directory -f file -v version -v app1 -v app2 -v app3
```

Comment: This will not work for my application unfortunately.  The script must pass arguments without flags.